# Umbraco add custom Document Type

Tags: user-controls, umbraco

Is it possible to add a custom control to the `Document Type`? Suppose i couldn't create a multiselect or just a simple textfield control. How could i create a custom one and use that from the `Document Type` page in Umbraco?

If this is possible, then what steps need to be taken? Because i can add all sorts of config information in the `Document Type` controls that currently exist in there. Like, when i add a `textfield` i can gvie it a `name`, an `alias` and a `validation` message (and it has some others options).

Do i have to build the custom Document Type control in a specific way? And how is it saved to the database? How does Umbraco handle that?

Any information on this matter is more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since adding custom *document types* is native to Umbraco, and judging by the description in your question, I'm going to assume that you are talking about adding custom *data types* with user controls.

If so, check some of the following links on the subject, it's actually fairly simple:

- [Creating custom datatypes using the umbraco usercontrol wrapper](http://www.nibble.be/?p=24) (I personally used this one)
- [Custom DataTypes in Umbraco](http://www.oshyn.com/_blog/Web_Content_Management/post/Custom_DataTypes_in_Umbraco/)
- [Creating a custom datatype using the usercontrol wrapper](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/developing-with-umbraco/data-editors/creating-a-custom-datatype-using-the-usercontrol-wrapper) (Video tutorial)